# Wordpress - get_post_meta() function not returning value?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm trying to get my Wordpress theme to pull up a thumbnail image for each post listed on the index page that I specify in a custom field added to the post in a field that is specified as 'image'. For whatever reason the get_post_meta() function isn't returning anything though, try as I might. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<div class="posts-wrapper">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <img src="<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true); ?>">

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: If I change the code to get_post_meta(the_id(), 'image', true); - then it simply outputs the post ID. For instance, one of my posts simply outputs the link as "6".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WordPress 2.9, there is a featured images function you can use for thumbnails that is much easier than using custom fields. Here's how to do it:

Add in functions.php:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { // Added in 2.9
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
 set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 200, true ); // Normal post thumbnails -- values: ( width, height, hard-crop-mode );
 add_image_size( 'home-post-thumbnail', 900, 300, true ); // Homepage thumbnail size
 add_image_size( 'single-post-thumbnail', 300, 9999 ); // Permalink thumbnail size
}
```

Then you just add this wherever you want the thumbnail to display:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail' ); // Change according to your thumbnail names ?>
```

And when you're writing a post, on the far right side of the page, there's a Featured Images section. Select your image and viola! :)

Answer (score 1):

you must echo the return value from the function `get_post_meta()`

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true); ?>">
```

Comment: Tried that, it still only outputs the post ID.

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress 5.4.2, I fetch meta fields as below and it works. Replace text "image" with your meta_key

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'image',true); echo $meta? $meta['text']: '';?>
```